# Segmentation fault 11 in MacOS X- C++

Tags: c++, data-structures, static

I have a "segmentation fault 11" error when I run the following code. The code actually compiles but I get the error at run time.

//** Terror.h **

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <map>

using std::map;
using std::pair;
using std::string;

template<typename Tsize>
class Terror
{
    public:
    //Inserts a message in the map.
    static Tsize    insertMessage(const string& message)
    {
        mErrorMessages.insert( pair<Tsize, string>(mErrorMessages.size()+1, message) );
        return mErrorMessages.size();
    }

    private:
    static map<Tsize, string>       mErrorMessages;
};

template<typename Tsize>
map<Tsize,string> Terror<Tsize>::mErrorMessages;
```

//** error.h **

```
#include <iostream>
#include "Terror.h"

typedef unsigned short errorType;
typedef Terror<errorType>   error;
errorType memoryAllocationError=error::insertMessage("ERROR: out of memory.");
```

//** main.cpp **

```
#include <iostream>
#include "error.h"
using namespace std;

int main()
{   
    try
    {
        throw error(memoryAllocationError);
    }
    catch(error& err)
    {
    }
}
```

I have kind of debugging the code and the error happens when the message is being inserted in the static map member. An observation is that if I put the line:

```
errorType memoryAllocationError=error::insertMessage("ERROR: out of memory.");
```

inside the "main()" function instead of at global scope, then everything works fine. But I would like to extend the error messages at global scope, not at local scope. The map is defined static so that all instances of "error" share the same error codes and messages. Do you know how can I get this or something similar.

Thank you very much.

Comment: The code you posted does not compile. Please fix it.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't seen your comment, It is corrected now. The problem was the ";" after the definition of the Terror<> class. Thank you.

Comment: It still does not compile because there is no constructor for `Terror` that takes a `Tsize` as a parameter.

Comment: Yes, there is a lot of more code that I didn't put here, I just wanted to point out the key part of the problem. Which I have already solved. Thank you very much. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to ensure that the constructor for `mErrorMessages` runs before you use it by calling `insertMessage`. You can do this any way you want, but you *must* do it somehow.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have followed your answer, but I can't find the way to call the constructor of "mErrorMessages" in such a way that I can populate it at global scope. Do you know one way that you could provide to me, or this is not possible and I should try another approach?

Comment: One way would be to give the class a pointer to the map and on calls to `insertMessage`, check if the pointer is NULL and, if so, to construct the map. Another way would be to put both objects in the same file -- objects at global scope in the same file are constructed in the order they appear in the file.

Comment: Thank you very much, Sr. David. Following your answer and searching a lot this two days, I got what I wanted. In case that someone else reads this, the way I solved my problem was to implement the following class inside the Terror<> template class:

Comment: struct codeMaps
{
    ~codeMaps()
    {
        if(messages) 
        {
            delete messages;
            messages=0;
        }
    }
        
    map<Tsize,string>*   messages;
};


And then I defined "mErrorMEssages" as:

static codeMaps mErrorMessages;

In this way, following David's advise, in every method that uses the mErrorMessage member I first check if "mErrorMessage.messages" was NULL or not, to make sure that the map<> was created before using it. And the destructor of the codeMaps class guarantees that the map is destroyed when the program finishes, in order to avoid leaks.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same issue when I tried to run on Mac OS X 10.7 an application I compiled for OS X 10.8.

Setting the target to 10.7 solved the problem. The application runs fine on both 10.7 and 10.8 OS X environments.